# How the code `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` works in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a question and an issue

Question:

The following code sends a request using `fetch`, gets response `res` (I suppose body of `HTTP` `200ok`), converts the body into `json`, assigns that to `data`. Am I correct?

. What is the type `setData`? How does `setData` work as I have not provided its implementation.

```
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/question")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`got response ${res}`);
        return res.json();
      }).then((data) => {
        console.log(`data : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
        setData(data)
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

        {!data ? "No data received" : data.map( d => (
          <div>  
            <p> Description: {d.description} </p>
            <p> Hints: {d.hints} </p>
            <p> Topic: {d.topic} </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Issue:
I am trying to use `map` on `data` but get error `data.map is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the `data` you get from fetching is not an array

Comment: Try logging `data`. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) hook allows us to hold some information in it for the component.

`useState` returns an array of two elements. First element will be the information and second element will be a function that can update the information.

That's why we [destructure while assigning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). For example, `const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);`

The information passed to `useState()` will be the initial value of the state. Here it's an empty array.

The problem here is the response you get from backend is not an array. It might possibly be an object. `.map()` function is for an array. So try transforming it to an array and set the state.

```
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/question")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`got response ${res}`);
        return res.json();
      }).then((data) => {
        console.log(`data : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          setData(data);
        } else {
           // Do something to transform it to an array
        }
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

        {!data ? "No data received" : data.map( d => (
          <div>  
            <p> Description: {d.description} </p>
            <p> Hints: {d.hints} </p>
            <p> Topic: {d.topic} </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Few questions - (1) If I know that the response will be `json` then I can pass `null` or empty object `({})` to `useState`? (2) - Would `setData` just override the previous value (as I haven't provided implementation of `setData` anywhere)? 3. If I want specific way to override value, can I provide my own implementation of `useState`?

Comment: 1) Yes, what you pass for `useState` will its initial state. You can pass whatever that is going to be set in future.

2) Yes.. Eg. setCount(2) will override the value and assign 2 to the state. But what happens this function is called asynchronously? This would assign wrong values right.. That's why we provide function implementation to `setState()`; Refer [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

3) Yes.. Just pass a function as mentioned in #2.